# Convert const T* const to T*

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

is it possibile do this kind of cast in C++?
I **need** to declare my attribute in this way.

```
Class A {
public:
  void update() { ++i_; }
private:
  int i_;  
}

Class B{
public:
   void foo() {
       a_->update(); /* Error */
   }
private:
 const A* const a_;
}
```

Error is:

> passing ‘const A’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void A::update()’ discards
>   qualifiers [-fpermissive]

I try with **static_cast**, but is not enough.. does not work.. any ideas?

Comment: As you see in the answers, you need to change your design. You have a pointer to `const` so the only way to call a non-`const` method on the object is `const_cast`. But then you *do* modify the object (`++i`) so this is undefined behaviour. Even if this works now, it won't work tomorrow. *Change your design*.

Comment: @iavr: Wait a minute `const_cast` does not necessarily mean *undefined behavior*; only if the object pointed to is created `const` in the first place do you have *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 3):

Using a const member with a non-const method is forbiden (unless using `mutable`). Put a `const` after declaration of `foo()` and `update()`:

```
void update() const { ...  }
              ^^^^^

void foo() const { ... }
           ^^^^^
```

or ...

If you don't want to make `update` a `const`, you can use `const_cast`:

```
void foo() const // Now, this const keyword is optional but recommanded
{
   const_cast<A*>(a_)->update();
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices here.  Either make A::update a const function-

```
Class A {
  void update() const;
}
```

or remove the constness of the pointer.

```
Class B{
public:
   void foo() {
       const_cast<A*>(a_)->update();
   }
private:
 const A* const a_;
}
```

The former would be the preferred method, but that will also stop you from doing anything useful in class A's update.

As a rule of thumb, if you have to cast the const off something then you really want to look at why the pointer is const in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few options:

- use `const_cast` to cast away the const and call the method.
- make `update` a const method, so that it can be called through a const pointer.
- don't store `a_` as const in the first place. Change it to `A* const a_` so that you can call non-const methods, but the pointer cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you cannot declare the method as `const` and that you know what you are doing (tm) and why this is bad: Try the `const_cast`!

Answer (score 0):

The const after * has nothing to do with it. You must declare your functions which use a_ as const functions. If they don't compile, you must use const_cast or reinterpret_cast to remove const from the pointer before calling.. But this is very dodgy, and if update() function modifies an object which was originally declared const, this is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get

> passing ‘const A’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void A::update()’ discards
>   qualifiers [-fpermissive]

is result of calling `non-const` method on a `const` pointer. This is forbidden. Since you require an update to be `non-const` and you cannot store a pointer to `non_const A`, you can use operator `const_cast` to cast away `const` and here is how to do it:

```
class A {
public:
  void update(){}
};

class B{
public:
   void foo() {
       const_cast< A*>(a_)->update(); /* OK*/
   }
private:
 const A* const a_;
};
```

You should however rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by someone before, use mutable/const but this changes your design a little bit:

```
class A {
public:
    void update() const { ++i_; } // this will make the method callable by const A*
private:
    mutable int i_;  // and this will make you field mutable in a const method
};

class B{
public:
    void foo() {
       a_->update(); 
    }
private:
    const A* const a_;
};
```